# URLEncoder not able to translate ")" (bracket) character

Tags: android

I am sending Json request to server. And Url has bracket character. I am got error Unexpected response code 500 for

```
 Unexpected response code 500 for http://admin.unimax.kz/api/Klientapi?login=+7(707)930-00-66&password=123456
```

Where beginning Bracket character url ending. And I think encoding doesn't work properly

request

```
void registerUser(){
        final String login = edt_phone.getText().toString().trim();
        final String pass = edt_pass1.getText().toString().trim();
        String fill_url = REGISTER_URL+"login="+Uri.encoding(login)+"&password="+ pass;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, fill_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if (response.equals("0"))
                        {
                            showDialog("Show");
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Show"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Here:  login= "+7(707)123-45-67" 
pass = "123456"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Suggest to create the query part URL first and encoded it using:
[URLEncoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Example:

```
String query = "?login=" + URLEncoder.encode(login, "UTF-8") + "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
String url = REGISTER_URL + query;
```